# ¿Por qué Buenos Aires se abrevia Bs. As. o B.A. y no BB.AA. como debería ser?

Tags: abreviaturas

Las abreviación de palabras en plural se hace usando dos veces la misma letra, por ejemplo *EE.UU.* por *Estados Unidos* o *II.BB.* por *Ingresos Brutos*. ¿Por qué no se utiliza la misma regla para Buenos Aires?

Comment: Es curiroso que Estados Unidos se abrevie EE UU y Buenos Aires Bs As.  Quiza la abreviatura de Buenos Aires se formó por un truncamiento de Buenos Aires, quitando todas las letras excepto las iniciales (BA o B. A.) y las "s" finales. Pero tienes toda la razon, parece uan excepcion en la manera de formar las abreviaturas.

Comment: El DPD menciona ambos casos, EE.UU. y Bs.As. Parece que la primera abreviatura fue formada mediante truncamiento y la segunda mediante contracción, pero el por qué no lo sé, ¿arbitrariedad del lenguaje? ¿mayor influencia de la forma anglosajona de pluralizar las abreviaturas?: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=fKODyKTfZD6s0mX7bz

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hay varias reglas aplicables cuando se hace una abreviación y están explicadas aquí:

[Diccionario panhispánico de dudas:Abreviatura](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=abreviatura)

> En abreviaturas formadas por una sola letra, el plural se expresa duplicando esta: ss. por siguientes, EE. UU. por Estados Unidos.

Buenos Aires como nombre propio no es plural del singular *Buen Aire*. Así pues se creo seguramente para diferenciarla y como excepción. No es el caso de:

- EE. UU. (Estados Unidos) -> Estado Unido.
- CC. OO. (Comisiones Obreras) -> Comisión Obrera.
- JJ. OO. (Juegos Olímpicos) -> Juego Olímpico
- AA. PP. (Administraciones Públicas) -> Administración Pública.

El hipotético caso de que existiera UU. EE. podría ser Uniones Europeas (¿pero si solo hay una Europa ?), no tiene sentido. Sería Us. Es. si existiera una ciudad para diferenciarla de la ya existente U. E. como Unión Europea.

Comment: Buenos Aires como nombre propio viene, segun la mayoria de los historiadores, del nombre de la virgen italiana _Madonna di Bonaria_, a quien le dieron el nombre en español de _Nuesta Señora del Buen Aire_. A mi me parece que _Buenos Aires_ sí es el plural de _Buen Aire_, ya que la ciudad originalmente se llamaba _Real de Nuestra Señora Santa María del Buen Ayre_, y en algun momento se convirtio en _Buenos Aires_. La palabra _aires_ es poco usada, pero si existe, y es por eso que la formacion de esta abreviatura no es muy clara.

Lo que es seguro es que la abreviatura es una excepcion.

Comment: Bs. As. tiene larga historia; B. A. nunca fue estándar, aunque aparecía más antes, y notablemente adaptada a la fonética inglesa en ciertos usos (*Biei* es el apodo del *Buenos Aires Cricket & Rugby Club*). Hoy se usa mucho CABA, *Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires*, que es la designación oficial, contrastada con AMBA *Área Metropolitana de Buenos Aires* y PBA *Provincia de Buenos Aires*.

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a la Real Academia Española, las palabras en plural se pueden abreviar de la siguiente manera:

> a) Si la abreviatura se obtuvo por truncamiento, se añade -s: págs.
>   por páginas. Se exceptúa el plural de las abreviaturas cent. (centavo,
>   centésimo) y cént. (céntimo), que es cts., y no cents. ni cénts. (no
>   debe confundirse la abreviatura cent. con la palabra cent, cuyo plural
>   sí es cents; → cent). En abreviaturas formadas por una sola letra, el
>   plural se expresa duplicando esta: ss. por siguientes, EE. UU. por
>   Estados Unidos.
>
> b) Si la abreviatura se obtuvo por contracción, se aplican las reglas
>   generales de formación del plural y se añade -s o -es según sea la
>   terminación (→ plural, 1): dptos. o deptos. por departamentos,
>   admones. por administraciones. Como excepción, Ud. (usted) forma el
>   plural en -s: Uds. (ustedes). El plural de las abreviaturas con letras
>   voladas debe representarse con este mismo tipo de letras: n.<sup>os</sup> por
>   números.
>
> c) Si la abreviatura corresponde a una forma verbal, para el plural se
>   usa la misma forma que para el singular: cp. vale como abreviatura de
>   compárese y de compárense; D. E. P. puede abreviar tanto Descanse en
>   paz como Descansen en paz.

En el caso de Buenos Aires siendo abreviada como Bs.As., parecería que la abreviatura se formó por truncamiento y se le agrego -s al final para denotar que es plural sin seguir la regla de abreviaturas en el momento de ser creada, y por convención no se ha cambiado a la forma que sería correcta. La RAE pone Bs.As. como una abreviatura convencional, por lo cual podemos asumir que al no ser formada con las reglas, es una excepción.

Por cierto, no he visto que se use mucho B.A. como abreviatura de Buenos Aires, por lo menos no en español.

---

Abreviaturas: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=fKODyKTfZD6s0mX7bz

Lista de abreviaturas convencionales: http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/apendices/abreviaturas

Comment: Rocco, en ese caso el DPD y la RAE estarían incurriendo en una contradicción. Otra interpretación que salva eso es que Buenos Aires se abrevió por contracción directamente desde el plural.

Comment: En mi experiencia B.A. como abreviatura de Buenos Aires es bastante común.

Comment: @Lucas, es posible que se haya abreviado por contraccion como tu dices, dado que esa parte de la regla no es muy clara. Dice asi: _"Por contracción, eliminando letras centrales dejando solo las más representativas"_. Por lo cual se deja a interpretacion individual el decidir que letras son representativas. ¿Por que no abreviar Bns. Ars.? Seria bueno saber la historia de la abreviatura de esta ciudad/provincial.