# How to say plural of abbreviations

Tags: plurales, abreviaturas

I'm wondering how one would say CDs, in Spanish.
I know that a single CD would be spelled in Spanish characters (i.e. "ce de"), however, how would several CDs be spelled in Spanish?

Comment: A related question about the abbreviation of ["Buenos Aires"](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/8759/5481)

Comment: Buenos Aires does not follow the rules for plurals, if you are talking about the capital city of Argentina.  In that context, BA is a singular even if it doesn't look like one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either add on an *-s* or *-es*, or just leave it as is with some other word marking its plural status.  I personally pluralize most of them, but it will depend on the degree of lexicalization of the initialism.

- un CD<sub>(cedé)</sub>, dos CD<sub>(cedé *o* cedés)</sub>
- un DVD<sub>(deuvedé)</sub>, dos DVD<sub>(deuvedé *o* deuvedés)</sub>
- un ONG<sub>(oenegé)</sub>, dos ONG<sub>(oenegé *o* oenegés)</sub>
- una DS<sub>(dese)</sub>, dos DS<sub>(dese *o* deses)</sub>
- un M16<sub>(emedieciséis)</sub>, dos M16<sub>(emedieciséis *o* emedieciseises)</sub>

Comment: And you can duplicate the letters in some acronyms, eg = **FF.AA.** = "fuerzas armadas".

Comment: M16 _(emedieciseises)?_ la verdad no había escuchado esta pronunciación en plural. Tengo curiosidad...¿es de algún país en específico?

Comment: Lo normal en México sería decir "DVDs" = (devedés) y DS = (De.ese). Tampoco estoy familiarizado con M16 en plural y aquí se acostumbra agregar la "s" minúscula para el plural.

Comment: Lo he escuchado con s de un colega que es coronel de origen portorriqueño, pero no suelo hablar de temas militares en español así, pero por eso dije que la S es facultativa. Casi todos dirán de(u)vedés, pero se admite sin S

Comment: No sé de dónde provendrá lo de *M16s - emedieciseises*, pero realmente no hay problema al pluralizar un número: «en 19166 hay dos unos, un nueve y dos seises».

Answer (score 1):

CD´S in spanish is the same form like english

but the pronunciation is (CE-DES)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tiene que ver con la región. No es lo mismo en España que en México o Argentina. En Argentina, por ejemplo, nadie dice "emedieciseises". Sería parecido a decir "pieses" o "viruses". Nosotros decimos **CDs (cedés)** y **DVD (devedés)**. El plural para M16 se lo ponemos en el contexto. Ejemplo: Juan compro varias **M16(emedieciseis)**